# Where are the Android API Demos?

Tags: android

From where can I download apidemos for Android 2.1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi dey are available in the folder android-sdk/samples/apidemos

Answer (score 14):

For API 18 its on `sdk/samples/android-18/legacy/ApiDemos` 
and 
for others its on `sdk/samples/android-x/ApiDemos`

Answer (score 7):

**`android.googlesource.com`**

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development is the official repository that contains the "API Demos" app at path [`samples/apidemos`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-6.0.1_r46/samples/ApiDemos/).

That repository is mirrored at: https://github.com/android/platform_development

`${SDK_DIR}/samples/` also contains many other interesting sample apps.

I was also maintaining some unofficial demos which are more minimal than the official ones: https://github.com/cirosantilli/android-cheat

Answer (score 4):

If you have just installed the Android plugin through Eclipse, check your `android-sdk-windows` folder for `SDKManager.exe`.

Double click on that and a window will pop up asking you which packages you want to install.

The APIDemos you are looking for will be in `samples for SDK API 7(8), revision 1`

These files shall be installed to the directory `/android-sdk/samples/...`

Answer (score 1):

As of 2015 Google has moved a number of their Android samples apps to github:

https://github.com/googlesamples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=android

Comment: That is a good way to search. Those repos are mirrors from https://android.googlesource.com

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's in :

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86\data\app

but it's just the APK for some reason

Answer (score 0):

And you can download API Demos application from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hmh.api)

Answer (score -1):

I found mine at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86\data\app\ApiDemos`.