# how to install android api demo app into my phone

Tags: android, demo, emulation

I'm learning android development.There is an apidemo app installed in the android emulator. I'd like have it installed in my real android phone so that I can use it without starting the emulator . How to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the Android API Demos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334268/where-are-the-android-api-demos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Api Demo is part of the SDK

Go to where your SDK is installed samples/android-X/ApiDemo

(X being the version of the sdk)

then install that project on your phone

Comment: Found it, thanks! there are lots demos in that directory. Great! Have to compile all them to apk myself ...

Comment: import/"create a new project from existing source" form that repertory and hit launch ^^

Comment: With a recent Eclipse/ADT setup: File > New > Other..., Android > Android Sample Project, pick the config you want, then pick the sample from the list.  Select the project and run it as an Android Application.

Comment: @Jason: what if we don't have Eclipse on our PC but we want to install those API on our real device? There is no .apk file there?

Answer (score 14):

In Eclipse Android plugin (ADT) there is a wizard for creating the sample projects.

In eclipse Go to:
File -> New -> Other ... -> type Android into search box -> Android Sample Project -> Next -> select your api level -> Select any of the samples, for example ApiDemos

Project called ApiDemos is created

Right click on it and select Run As -> Android Application

Comment: In ADT 22.3.0, ApiDemo is marked as 'legacy' and its README says: "..use the compatibility library android-support-v4.jar. It is available through the SDK Updater in the Android Compatibility package." What it means is: In Android SDK Manager, have Extras / Android Support Library installed. Right click ApiDemos project > Android Tools > Add Support Library. Not sure if both are needed, at least the latter one is.

Answer (score 3):

In order open api demo in your eclipse 
File>new>Android Project
From that '`New Android Project`' window, you select `Create Project from existing sample`
When you select your `target`, you can select '`Api-demo`' from the `samples` list
This will open the complete api demo in your eclipse and when you run this project in `device` you will get it in device also. you can edit and use it as you wish.