# List Image Buttons next to each other and breaks into a new line

Tags: java, android, adb

I want to add image buttons next to each other, and once it reaches the end of the LinearLayout it should go into the next row.

Note : API Level 10

**What I probably need to do, but I don't know how :**

- Calculate end of parent width
- Add top margin value calculated by row number
- Set image button to parent's left

If there is a better way, please post it.

**Here is my testing code :**

```
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        paramsLO.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paramsLO.height = 150;
        paramsLO.width = 150;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20;i++)
        {
            ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(this);
            imgBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
            imgBtn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            layout.addView(imgBtn,paramsLO);
        }

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the FlowLayout
here is a good lib [flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout), simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the ApiDemos -> Animation -> LayoutAnimations.

I think this is **exactly** what you are looking for.

See these links if you don't know how to install the ApiDemos.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467915/2538428
http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look and let you know.