# android home screen widget layout change on click event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, homescreen

I am developing an android home screen widget for my ToDo app. It shows 3 Todos at a time on the widget layout. I mean my widget layout can accommodate only 3 TextViews.

Now, I have another TextView(besides the three TextViews for my Todo list) on the widget with android:text="Flip". I want that whenever I click on this "Flip" the other set of 3 Todos should be shown. Again, when the user clicks on it the previous set of 3 Todos should be shown. And the process continues.

How can i gain control over the TextView?

Comment: You may want to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will generate more helpful answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in `onUpdate()` method of your `AppWidgetProvider` class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are looking for is exactly done in the [APIDemos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334268/android-api-demos), download it or look for it if you already have it.

Comment: I did it. I don't think it has my answer.